# correct term for the "next to latest ( item before the latest)

Tags: single-word-requests

i am informing my website readers that i have added the latest page. please tell me the proper name for the page that is now just before the latest page. it is not the "next to last" as, hopefully, there will still be more to add soon

Comment: [Penultimate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate)

Comment: @HotLicks: OP specifically (and rightly) says this is wrong, since *latest* is not *last*.

Comment: It is the 'next to last page' ... until you add even more.

Comment: @TimLymington - Depends on how you read it.  The OP's specification is incredibly unclear.

Comment: Dear OP: please, PLEASE use standard English capitalization. Some respect towards those you expect to answer your question is most definitely in order.

Comment: 'Second most recent'

Answer (score 1):

The "latest but one" is often found:

> 'Ah! The latest but one was that Willie had gone around saying
>   definitely he wasn't a target, so his death had to be just to divert
>   suspicion.
>
> The world window will be what it was after the latest-but-one drawing,
>   so that you can use the Margins menu as if the latest drawing had
>   never happened.
>
> Kinnon adds, "Go live with the latest, or latest but one, version, use
>   the business process methodology that Epicor advises, and do the
>   process mapping correctly
>
> Try modifying the 'checkpoint' text file within the directory to
>   change the pointer to the latest but one file, thus telling TF to load
>   a prior ckpt version.
>
> Ni-MH batteries, short for nickel-metal hydride, are the latest but
>   one in battery technology - the latest being Li-ion.

Answer (score 0):

Does **previous page** not work?

If not, then you can use **next to most recent**.